# Delete Query Not Deleting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I'm wondering why the first delete query won't work, when the second does?

```
if(isset($_POST['accept request' . $user_from])) {
    $delete_request = mysql_query("DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE user_from='$user_from' AND user_to='user_to'");
    header("location: friend_requests.php");

    echo "<br /><br />You are now friends with " . $user_to;

}

if(isset($_POST['ignorerequest' . $user_from])) {
    $delete_request = mysql_query("DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE user_from='$user_from' AND user_to='$user_to'");
    header("location: friend_requests.php");
    echo "Friend Request Declined";
}
```

Please ignore the fact that they're not prepared, and that it's a security issue. I purely want to know why the first delete request doesn't work (yes, the if gets triggered properly)

Comment: ignoring to what you want to ignore. And still, this is not regrettable: WHERE IS YOUR ERROR HANDLING?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a debugging request with a program malfunction while the OP shows no minimal efforts of error handling at all.

Comment: Why do you use "echo" when anyways you redirect? echo won't be displayed

Comment: @Zerquix18 I know, I have it there from before.

Comment: People should really start to learn **basic** debugging.

Comment: I mean you don't even have to debug here, you have two queries which are EXACT the same just 1 character missing and you don't see it?

Comment: Can I just get an answer? Or is debugging the only you care about. I've tried, I don't get any errors. It just doesn't work. 
@Xatenev the first one doesn't work if it's just that one, and the second doesn't exist. It's not that.

Comment: No you can't because you obviously didn't try anything to fix your code. Anyways, debugging **should** be the only thing you care about when you have a problem. Just put a $ sign before user_to in your first query.

Comment: @Xatenev No, you're wrong. I spent 10 minutes looking EVERYTHING over to make sure it was correct. The human brain has an automatic spellcheck to allow us to skip over typos and stuff without even noticing. You can't say I didn't try if I did.

Comment: 10 Minutes. Be careful that you don't debug too long or your brain might get damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your missing the dollar sign on your user_to variable

```
"DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE user_from='$user_from' AND user_to='$user_to'"
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me an answer. :)